# springdoc-openapi-ui add JWT header parameter to generated swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

In my spring boot app I have endpoints which are validated by header parameter in my springboot app.
Current swagger json looks like this:

```js
// part of current swagger.json
...
  "paths": {
    "/path1/{param1}": {
      "get": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "param1",
            "in": "path",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
...
```

I want to add missing parameter using `springdoc-openapi-ui` configuration so it would look like this:

```js
// I want to achieve swagger.json which contains additional parameter
...
  "paths": {
    "/path1/{param1}": {
      "get": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "param1",
            "in": "path",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          },
          {
            "name": "missingParam",
            "in": "header",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
...
```

I tried achieving that by adding to my `appplication.yml` solution from [Common Parameters for Various Paths](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#common-for-various-paths)

```yaml
#application.yml
...
components:
  parameters:
    hiddenParam:
      in: header
      name: missingParam
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
paths:
  /path1:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/hiddenParam'
```

But it doesn't work.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to modify my swagger result using application configuration?
2. I want to define parameter template and add it to all endpoints, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add the global parameters like header using `OperationCustomizer` as shown below. This will add your `parameter` to every service

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OperationCustomizer customGlobalHeaders() {

        return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {

            Parameter missingParam1 = new Parameter()
                    .in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString())
                    .schema(new StringSchema())
                    .name("missingParam1")
                    .description("header description2")
                    .required(true);
                    
            Parameter missingParam2 = new Parameter()
                    .in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString())
                    .schema(new StringSchema())
                    .name("missingParam2")
                    .description("header description2")
                    .required(true);

            operation.addParametersItem(missingParam1);
            operation.addParametersItem(missingParam2);

            return operation;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for input, this works. Additional question, how can I exclude some path from customization? As it turns out I have one endpoint which should not be customized.

Comment: It will apply for all the paths as far as I know we can't exclude a particular path. One this you can do is define the parameter and use it using `$ref` for all the applicable paths

Comment: You can find more here https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-set-a-global-header

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as this solves my original question. As I changed approach to my problem I added another answer with my final solution, thx.

Answer (score 20):

Finally I decided to use different approach.
I defined [security scheme](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-define-securityscheme-) and applied it globally as [authorization header](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-do-i-add-authorization-header-in-requests).

```java
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("My App").version("1.0.0"))
                // Components section defines Security Scheme "mySecretHeader"
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes("mySecretHeader", new SecurityScheme()
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                                .name("missingParam")))
                // AddSecurityItem section applies created scheme globally
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("mySecretHeader"));
    }
```

Now `swagger-ui.html` allows testing endpoints with authorization header or without it according to tester requirements.
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: thanks, it is an awesome solution and it works smoothly

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to configure this through application.yml also?

Comment: I didn't verify it but take a look [Bearer Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)

Comment: Is there any way to add default values to these headers?

Comment: Finally, a good solution that works.